# Helper method Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If we are passing capitalize method to already capitalize string then why it is returning NIL rather it should return the same capitalize string. Let me know where I am going wrong.
e.g

```
    first_name = "Manish"
    first_name.capitalize!
    => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly stated in the documentation that [`capitalize!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21) returns `nil` if no changes are made.

> **capitalize! → str or nil**
>
> Modifies str by converting the first character to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase. Returns nil if no changes are made. Note: case conversion is effective only in ASCII region.

Answer (score 0):

Doc says about [String#capitalize!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21):

> Modifies str by converting the first character to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase. ***Returns nil if no changes are made***. Note: case conversion is effective only in ASCII region.

Now as you are saying - *If we are passing capitalize method to already capitalize string then why it is returning NIL rather it should return the same capitalize string*

Yes that happened only when you would use [String#capitalize](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize), instead of `String#capitalize!`. As per the documentation -

> Returns a copy of str with the first character converted to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase. **If the string in already *capitalized*, then return the receiver itself.**

```
first_name = "Manish"
first_name.capitalize # => "Manish"
first_name.capitalize! # => nil
```